# saveOrUpdate() without primary key

Tags: hibernate, save

I have a data that I want to be either saved or updated if already exists.
So saveOrUpdate() but only If I know a primary key.

I could call select from database to find out the id, before that every task, but is there a better way?

EDIT:

Basicly I have db table of tvshow episodes (1000+ objects). And when I so called order an tvshow and want to add the for exammple 60 episodes to database,  then I have to have an if check(select call to recieve Primary Key) before every single episode insertion. Does that sound like it should be?

Answer (score 0):

If you known the primary key in advance and you are sure row with that PK exists you can use
`Session.get(Serializable id)` instead of `Session.load(Serializable id)`; `get()` will create an object of desidered type without hitting the database.
In other situation you can't have an `@Entity` without an `@Id` (you will get an error during Hibernate startup) hence if you are using `Session.saveOrUpdate(obj)` you have `obj` primary key, by design.

Comment: I do not know the primary key.

Comment: you have to get it from db. Or update using business key (via Criteria/HQL) or [natural id](http://relation.to/Bloggers/41FeatureLoadingByNaturalId)